# Can I make the default constructor of a class generated from a Kotlin file private?

Tags: kotlin

If I create a Kotlin file `MyTest.kt`

```
package my.test
fun sayHello(): String = "Hello"
```

A class `MyTestKt` will be generated and it can be accessed from java like this:

```
MyTestKt.sayHello() // Returns "Hello"
MyTestKt myTestKt = new MyTestKt() // Instantiate
```

I would like to make that constructor private. Is that possible? If so, how?

---

I know I can use an `object` to create a singleton, that is not my question. I know I can create a class with a `companion object` inside, that is also not my question.

Comment: There is no way to do that right now.

Comment: Interesting question! Unfortunately, I don't see a way to do it. That's propably a question for the language devs

Comment: What would happen if you did in the file: class MyTestKt private constructor () {}
 and then after the stub class did
fun sayHello(): String = "Hello"

Comment: @Adam by doing that a class `MyTestKt` is created with a private constructor, but it does not contain the method `sayHello` and I have no idea who owns that method.

Comment: @Adam Ohhh when I try to actually run the app, it tells me that there is a duplicated class `MyTestKt`, so, it is not an option. But good idea though... Thanks

Comment: As a workaround you could use a class with a private constructor and a [JVMStatic](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-static/) method, if that fulfills what you want to do, but I don't think it's exactly what you want.

Comment: I know I can use `object` + `@JvmStatic`. I can also use `class` + `companion object` + `private constructor()` + `@JvmStatic`. And that will give more or less the same result. But I am really trying to understand how the Kotlin file works and how it can be manipulated... Thanks @jrtapsell

Comment: Curious. Why does it matter? Is this intellectual curiosity, or a situation you've experienced? 

If another class constructs the object, all it has access to is the static method. An editor, or static analysis, or code review should provide warning of this situation.

And like others, I'm not aware of a way to achieve what you want, so I'm no help there.

Comment: @Mikezx6r When writing `Utils`-like classes in Java I always make the constructor private to prevent instantiation. Just wanted to do the same in Kotlin. All the alternatives presented `object` and `companion object` seem like a workaround. If I could make the constructor of the generated class private, to me, it would be the best solution for a clean code.

Comment: Fair enough. I suspect the designers were thinking more of Kotlin usage, and the Kt class is a necessity to work on the JVM. Given that, I agree that it should automatically generate a private constructor. Could always raise an issue/suggestion on the Youtrack for Kotlin. And agree the suggestions are merely workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
@file:JvmName("Utils")

package demo

fun foo() {}
class Utils private constructor()
```

When you try to call Utils constructor from Java you get a "Utils has private access"

UPDATE
When using a private constructor() you are not able to access foo function. 
I think this could be a design flaw, having a function not associated to any class-object. I have look into several kotlin standard library and I only found extension-functions as you want. In that case, for example, `CollectionKt`, it cannot be instantiated.

Comment: But that is what I said in my comment... you can't access `foo`